# How to hide safely remove device from non-admin users

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have users that I would like to disable from unmounting volumes because they do not have physical access to the machine. If they unmount a device the only way that they could remount it would be to reboot the machine and wait for the OS to automatically remount newly detected devices upon bootup. This is obviously undesirable so I would prefer if I could prevent them from unmouting devices. A GPO would be nice, but if there is a registry entry for it that would work as well.

Comment: (just for info) There *are* some registry keys... (although I hadn't the greatest of luck in using them). Can't recall the source, but they exist.

Comment: Same question on serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/364311/how-to-disable-safely-remove-hardware

Answer (score 1):

According to [raymond.cc](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/hide-or-remove-safely-remove-hardware-tray-icon/), running the following script will do it:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\SysTray" /v "Services" /t reg_dword /d 29 /f
systray
```

The downside is that it means re-running systray after setting the value which may make it harder to do via policy. The key also exists in the HKLM hive, so that may be worth experimenting with as well.